# Adding two columns together and writing the sum into one column using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I need to write code that will fill in a column with the sum of the two preceding columns off an excel worksheet for the rows that I specify. I am using python 3.6 and openpyxl. I have tried a few different variations of the following:

```
import openpyxl

from openpyxl import load_workbook

from openpyxl.compat import range

wb = load_workbook(filename='test.xlsx')

ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for row in range(1, 15):
    for col in range(4, 5):
        value = ws['B'].value + ws['C'].value
```

When I save it, nothing happens. Does anyone know how I can get it to add the two columns inot the next one without having to specify the row?

Comment: Please supply working code, so including how you saved this could be the source of the problem.

Comment: You're trying to add columns together and this makes no sense. You must add ranges, eg. `ws['B5'] = "sum(B1:B4)"` if you can let Excel do the adding for you otherwise you'll have to write your own sum function for the relevant columns `(sum(c.value for c in ws['B'])`

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few things I am not seeing.

```
wb.save('file_name.xlsx')
```

Which will make the save of your file thus providing a change and you might see something happen.

You need to provide the location of the cell you want the calculation to appear in. i.e.

```
b_col, c_col = ['B', 'C']
for row in range(1, 15):
    result_cell = 'A{}'.format(row)

    b_value = ws[b_col + str(row)].value
    c_value = ws[c_col +str(row)].value

    ws[result_cell] =  b_value + c_value
```

Working on a simple function like this though, I'd use an excel function:

```
for row in range(1, 15):
    result_cell = 'A{}'.format(row)
    add_function = '=B{}+C{}'.format(row)

    ws[result_cell] = add_function
```